# Why does this jQuery color picker fail within a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the excellent jQuery color picker from http://colpick.com/plugin

It works correctly under "normal" circumstances but doesn't show the picker when the input parent element is found within a Bootstrap 3 modal.

This works:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="colorPick1" class="colorPick"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the same thing inside a Bootstrap modal fails to show the picker:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="colorPick2" class="colorPick"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use this color picker within a Bootstrap modal?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is `z-index` just add this line in your css class it works good..

```
.colpick {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

[Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8a8rj/)